# How to have latexmk always use -shell-escape?

Tags: latexmk, shell-escape

<sub><sup>I haven't seen this asked specifically, though I have seen related questions.</sup></sub>

I just installed the `minted` package and noticed I have to run `latex`/`pdflatex` with a command-line option, `-shell-escape`, for it to run. I can do that manually, of course, but what if I'm using `latexmk`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass the parameter directly to `latexmk` as such:

```
latexmk -shell-escape
```

This option is not mentioned in the manpage. The manpage suggests the `-e` option which is also used in the first answer. This option amongst many others can be found using

```
latexmk -showextraoptions
```

The command output starts with the following note:

> List of extra latex and pdflatex options recognized by latexmk.
> These are passed as is to (pdf)latex.  They may not be recognized by
> particular versions of (pdf)latex. [..]

Tested with `latexmk` versions

- 1 January 2015. Version 4.41
- 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67

Comment: Are you sure what it does is invoke pdflatex with -shell-escape?

Comment: Yes, I added part of the note that `latexmk -showextraoptions` starts with.

Answer (score 26):

If you need to do this just once, run:

```
latexmk -e '$latex=q/latex %O -shell-escape %S/'
```

or

```
latexmk -e '$pdflatex=q/pdflatex %O -shell-escape %S/' -pdf
```

for PDF output.

If you want `latexmk` to *always* run with this option enabled, you should put the following in your `.latexmkrc` file (yes, that's a thing):

```
$latex = 'latex  %O  --shell-escape %S';
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex  %O  --shell-escape %S';
```

> #### Caveat!
>
> Enabling `--shell-escape` by default is dangerous, since it makes the latex binary execute arbitrary shell commands in latex files.**

Comment: You can also consider creating a `Makefile` (or a script, be it bash or cmd), if you want to have `--shell-escape` on a per-project basis.

Comment: What is `q/` for?

Comment: The `q/` is explained in the documentation as *In this example, the `q/.../` construct is a Perl idiom equivalent to single quotes.* It is about escaping and proper quoting.

Comment: Is there supposed to be extra spacing around the `%O` in the `.latexmkrc` sample?

Comment: Umm... I don't think so. Don't remember why the extra spacing is in there. Try removing it and check to make sure nothing has gotten messed up.

Answer (score 9):

To enable `shell-escape` for all `*latex` commands using a `latexmkrc` file:

```perl
set_tex_cmds( '--shell-escape %O %S' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had lots of problems with tikz externalize and pgfplots to be externalized and compiled separately (which worked in the past at some point). Now, I know this is not a solid thing to do, but it works! Thanks mate!