# Latexmk + \tikzexternalize won't update

Tags: texstudio, tikz-external, latexmk

I'm using TexStudio 2.10.8 and I'm currently looking into the `pgfplots` package. Now I'm trying to get the `\tikzexternalize` command to work properly.
After some time I convinced TexStudio to pass the `--shell-escape` parameter in order to make the whole thing work.

It will now indeed externalize my plots in their own pdf files but they won't get updated when chaning them in the source file. O have to manually delete the respective externalized files in order for the change to appear in my document.

I'm using `latexmk` with the following arguments `latexmk -pdf -silent -latexoption="-synctex=1" %` and `pdflatex` is configured like this: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`

I tried switching to `pdflatex` directly and then everything works fine as expected but as soon as I switch back to `latexmk` the plots won't get updated again.

Does anyone know how to get that to work? Am I missing something?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{script}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
            title=Inv. cum. normal,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            minor x tick num=1
        ]

        \addplot [
            blue,
            mark=+
        ] table {TestData.csv};
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \hskip 10pt % insert a non-breaking space of specified width.
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
        yticklabel pos=upper
    ]
    % density of Normal distribution:
    \addplot [
    red,
    domain=-3e-3:3e-3,
    samples=201,
    ]
    {exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You must configure the latexmk call so that it adds the --shell-escape, see the documentation of latexmk.

Comment: That's what I tried first but TexStudio won't let me do that (or rather it erases the complete `latexmk` configuration when changing it. And before I added the the option to `pdflatex` I got an error message and nothing has been externalized. Afterwards the message was gone and the externalization was there but as stated in the question only once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`latexmk` woulnd't know what you configured in texstudio, so you need to feed the correspondig option to `latexmk`:

```
latexmk -e '$pdflatex=q/pdflatex %O -shell-escape %S/' -pdf
```

(borrowed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374160/how-to-have-latexmk-always-use-shell-escape))

Also, setting `\tikzset{external/force remake}` allows you to rebuild all externalized plots, so you can add a commented version of that and toggle when needed.

Comment: That makes sense to me but why was latexmk even able to externalize the whole thing in the first place (which it couldn't do before I set the parameter for `pdflatex` in TexStudio)?

Answer (score 0):

Alright as Ulrike Fischer mentioned in the comments and Diego 72 in his answer the problem indeed was that I had to pass the `--shell-escape` option to `latexmk` and not `pdflatex`.

That is what I first tried but TexStudio would keep erasing the `latexmk` options field after exiting the preferences (if I had changed them) so I tried changing the ones of `pdflatex` which resulted in the files getting externalized without any errors or warnings (why this is so: I don't have a clue).

However as soon as I switched to the `Advanced Settings` in TexStudio I was actually able to edit and save the `latexmk` preferences (found it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/77a78ca8/)) so I simply changed it to `latexmk -pdf -silent -latexoption="-synctex=1 --shell-escape" %` and now everything works like charm.

I don't know if this bug has been fixed in recent TexStudio versions or if they call it a feature but I just wanted to document the workaround to it in case anyone is stumbling across the same problem I had (and by any luck across this question here).