# In a texlive environment, how to sovlve the "I can not access the shell" problem?

Tags: texlive, markdown, texlive-2020

When I try to include a markdown snippet in my tex code:

```
\usepackage[hashEnumerators,smartEllipses]{markdown}

\begin{markdown}

An h1 header
============

\end{markdown}
```

I got the following error:

```
Package markdown: I can not access the shell.
```

What's the cause of this problem and how do I fix it?

I'm using mklatex under Windows 11

Comment: You need to compile with the `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` flags.

Comment: thanks for the instruction, what's the mechanism of these 2 flags? Are these for pandoc? latexmk? pdflatex?

Comment: They're for pdflatex (or xelatex, lualatex, etc.) and they allow it to make use of external programs, such as pandoc. They do the same thing, so you only need one. I believe latexmk also has a `--shell-escape` option which will prompt it to use that option when it calls pdf/xe/latex. See e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426227/how-to-enable-shell-escape-when-building-with-latexmk-and-xelatex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374160/how-to-have-latexmk-always-use-shell-escape).